# window.setinterval() function stops by itself

Tags: javascript

How can i prevent window.setInterval() function stopping by itself? The function runs for a short period then stops. I want the setInterval function to run perpetually. Thanks.

```
var id = window.setInterval(function() {
  reloadIFrame()
}, 10000);

function reloadIFrame() {
  console.log('reloading..');
  document.getElementById('c').contentWindow.location.reload();
  setTimeout(5000);
  // do stuff here
}
```

Comment: what's `setTimeout(5000);` doing there?

Comment: Calls to `setTimeout()` with nonsense parameters just do nothing, silently. There's no error thrown.

Comment: @Manav.....setTimeout is to allow the previous .reLoad to fully load the page because subesquent code needs the page.

Comment: @Carcigenicate.....it is not that the function doesn't work at all. it works for a while and then stops.

Comment: @AyoOwoade Well, besides the noop `setTimeout(5000);` call, there's nothing obvious that's wrong. Are you sure it doesn't have anything to do with the `// do stuff here` part that you omitted? And are you sure there's no errors in the console? Keep the console open until it fails.

Comment: And the call to `setTimeout` doesn't do what you think it does. It doesn't work like Java's `Thread/sleep`. Run `console.log(1); setTimeout(2000); console.log(2);` to see. It will print 1 then 2 immediately. `setTimeout` takes a callback like `setInterval`.